# DBIx::Class update only one row

Tags: mysql, catalyst, dbix-class

I am using [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class) and I would like to only update one row in my table. Currently this is how I do it:

```
my $session = my_app->model("DB::Session")->find(1);    
$session->update({done_yn=>'y',end_time=>\'NOW()'});
```

It works, but the problem is that when it does find to find the row, it does this whole query:

```
SELECT me.id, me.project_id, me.user_id, me.start_time, me.end_time, me.notes, me.done_yn FROM sessions me WHERE ( me.id = ? ): '8'
```

Which seems a bit much when all I want to do is update a row. Is there anyway to update a row without having to pull the whole row out of the database first? Something like this is what I am looking for:

```
my_app->model("DB::Session")->update({done_yn=>'y',end_time=>\'NOW()'},{id=>$id});
```

Where `$id` is the `WHERE id=?` part of the query. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run update on a restricted resultset which only matches this single row:

`my_app->model("DB::Session")->search_rs({ id=> 1 })->update({done_yn=>'y',end_time=>\'NOW()'});`

I suggest you use a DateTime->now object instead of literal SQL for updating the end_time column because it uses the apps servers date and time instead of the database servers and makes your schema more compatible with different RDBMSes.

Comment: So that's good because it's done in one line, but is that really two sql statements because it has to find the resultset first?

Comment: search(_rs) only restricts the resultset definition, no SQL is generated or run until you call all or next on it or use it in list context.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a check if the row was found to prevent an error in case it wasn't?

You might want to use [update_or_create](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aResultSet#update_or_create) instead.

Comment: I know this is late, but this actually ended up working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "columns" attribute:

```
my $session = my_app->model("DB::Session")->find(1, {columns => "id"});
```

Comment: In general, allowing `find()` to retrieve the columns you wish to update, as well as the primary key, enables `update()` to not issue an UPDATE statement if it doesn't really need to (i.e., the new data is the same as the existing data).  Of course, this isn't relevant in your case.

Comment: But how does this make it one query? After that don't I still have to run the update on the row that I found?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.